# How to bind external methods in Router.routes in Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Is it possible to bind methods from other object in the **Router.routes** map?

I have all the "logic code" inside of **Views** and I would like to avoid define methods in the **Router**.

For instance, I have this:

```
var app = new (Backbone.View.extend({    
         playHome: function(){
            // logic code here
         }
//..........
});
var router = new (Backbone.Router.extend({
        routes: {
          "play"         : 'playHome'
        },
        playHome: function(){
            app.playHome();
        }
```

I woud like to do something like this:

```
var router = new (Backbone.Router.extend({
        routes: {
          "play"         : 'app.playHome'
        },
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Is the bounty still on, What answer you expect from what John provided

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a fairly easy way to accomplish what you want:

```
  var WorkspaceRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
      "help": "help", // #help
      "search/:query": "search", // #search/kiwis
      "search/:query/p:page": "search" // #search/kiwis/p7
    },

    help : function () { },

    search : function () { }
  });

  var App = {
    help: function() { console.log("help"); },

    search: function(query, page) { console.log("search", query, page); }
  };

  $(document).ready(
      function () {
        var router = new WorkspaceRouter();
        Backbone.history.start();

        router.on("route:help", App.help);
        router.on("route:search", App.search);
      }
  );
```

This solution relies on the fact that Backbone fires an event for each route as well as calling a function on the router itself. If you're willing to allow the dummy functions on the router that do nothing then you can attach whatever you like to the router's events and call any number of other functions on other objects, attaching the whole thing (or detaching it) as needed.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [Backbone.Marionette's AppRouter](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.approuter.md).. it allows you to provide a controller object which just has to provide the needed route methods.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way to accomplish what you're looking for...

```
var app = new (Backbone.View.extend({    
    playHome: function(){
        // logic code here
    }
    //..........
});

var router = new (Backbone.Router.extend({
    initialize: function(){
        // route,  route name for event, callback function
        this.route("play", "playRoute", _.bind(app.playHome, app))
    },
```

It's calling `app.playHome` as the callback function for the route, with `app` bound as `this` for the callback.

Answer (score 0):

I think I read this somewhere, where? no idea. But you can pass first-class functions as values to the routes object. This way:

```
var router = new (Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
      "play"         : app.playHome
    },
```

No guarantees though! Wonder where I read this. Hope this helps

Comment: unfortunately, it doesn't work. No error is throw but the function is not called.  Thanks anyway.